# How to configure VLANs along with Libvirt/KVM/QEMU and OVS?

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, vlan, openvswitch

I am using Debian 9 machine as a router with two interfaces:

```
eth0 for WAN
eth1 for LAN
```

The eth1 has subinterfaces for multiple VLANs (eth1.10; eth1.20; eth1.30) and has trunk connection to managed switch. Various devices are connected to the switch access ports and have Internet access. Pretty standard setup, everything works as expected.

Now what I am trying to do is to create few VMs right inside the Debian router using libvirt/KVM/Qemu and connect them using OVS bridge to the existing VLANs. Something like recreating the same physical configuration as I described above, but virtualized.

I tried to create ovsbr0, add eth1 port to bridge and then add tagged ports for particular VLANs I wanted the VMs to connect to like this:

```
# ovs-vsctl add-br ovsbr0
# ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 eth1
# ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vnet1 tag=10
# ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vnet2 tag=20
# ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vnet3 tag=30
```

When I run the actual VMs, the bridge looks like this:

```
# ovs-vsctl show
   Bridge ovsbr0
       Port ovsbr0
           Interface ovsbr0
               type: internal
       Port "eth1"
           Interface "eth1"
       Port "vnet1"
           tag: 10
           Interface "vnet1"
       Port "vnet2"
           tag: 20
           Interface "vnet2"
       Port "vnet3"
           tag: 30
           Interface "vnet3"
```

To my suprise the VMs vnet interfaces have no connection. From tcpdump on eth1, I can see that ARP frames from VMs are correctly tagged and reaching eth1 interface, but are not for some reason forwarded to the subinterfaces. I have never used OVS before, so I am obviously missing something important, but cannot figure out what it is.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OVS bridge will forward traffic only to ports that are part of actual configured bridge. Although the eth1 is correctly added to the bridge as trunk interfaces, the subinterfaces (eth1.10; eht1.20; eth1.30) are not part of the bridge and would never see the traffic.
The solution is simple - just add mentioned VLAN subinterfaces to the bridge.